# C Program - Why is my card shuffling function not working correctly?

Tags: c, swap, shuffle

I'm creating a card shuffling function which iterates through a passed array, calls another function swap to change each element on pass with another and stores that element into another array called shuffledDeck. Im then returning the shuffled deck from the function. I am getting some shuffled cards on calling the function but most stay in the same place. I'm not sure why the rest of the deck isn't moving like the others. Could anyone point out anything wrong with my functions that would explain the output?

Initialized deck vs output that im getting from my function.

```
Unshuffled 

[AH] [2H] [3H] [4H] [5H] [6H] [7H] [8H] [9H] [10H] [JH] [QH] [KH] 
[AD] [2D] [3D] [4D] [5D] [6D] [7D] [8D] [9D] [10D] [JD] [QD] [KD] 
[AC] [2C] [3C] [4C] [5C] [6C] [7C] [8C] [9C] [10C] [JC] [QC] [KC] 
[AS] [2S] [3S] [4S] [5S] [6S] [7S] [8S] [9S] [10S] [JS] [QS] [KS] 

Shuffled 

[AD] [AH] [2H] [3H] [4H] [5H] [6H] [7H] [8H] [9H] [10H] [JH] [QH] 
[KH] [KH] [2D] [3D] [4D] [5D] [6D] [7D] [8D] [9D] [10D] [JD] [QD] 
[KD] [AC] [2C] [3C] [4C] [5C] [6C] [7C] [8C] [9C] [10C] [JC] [QC] 
[KC] [AS] [2S] [3S] [4S] [5S] [6S] [7S] [8S] [9S] [10S] [JS] [QS]
```

My functions

```
void swap(char *(*deck)[13], int r, int c)
{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    int rowToSwap = -1;  //will hold generated row and column to swap
    int colToSwap = -1;
    
    while(rowToSwap < 0 || rowToSwap > 3 && colToSwap < 0 || colToSwap > 12){ //while row to swap and col to swap are outside appropriate ranges
        rowToSwap = rand() % (3 + 1 - 0);
        colToSwap = rand() % (12 + 1 - 0);
    }
    char *temp = deck[rowToSwap][colToSwap];    //swap by elements using a temp holder
    deck[rowToSwap][colToSwap] = deck[r][c];
    deck[r][c] = temp;
}


char *(*shuffleDeck(char *(*deck)[13]))[13]
{
    char *(*shuffledDeck)[13] = malloc(4 * sizeof(*shuffledDeck));

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
            swap(deck, i, j);
            shuffledDeck[i][j] = deck[i][j];
        }
        
    }
    return shuffledDeck;
}
```

Comment: `rowToSwap < 0 || rowToSwap > 4` seems incorrect to me, as there are only 4 rows, but you iterate 5 times (`[0,1,2,3,4]`) where `deck[4]` will produce a segfault at best, or undefined behaviour at worst...

Comment: @gkhaos true, made that fix but the output I'm getting is still the same

Comment: You should call `srand` only once in your program, not every time you call `swap`.

Comment: Why do you copy each card into the second array before you are done with shuffling? Whenever you swap a card with another card that was accessed earlier, this card will not be stored in the second array again. You should copy the cards only after everything is done.

Comment: Although unlikely to be the reason of this problem, a general advice: there is no reason to initialize the random number generator (`srand`) every time you shuffle a pair, it's purpose is to get different trajectories based on the initial seed (the parameter for `srand`), and to get same trajectories using the same seed for debugging purposes. Relation to your problem: There is a chance, that the RNG is initialized with the same value over and over again, which will lead to a non-uniform distribution of pseudo-random numbers

Comment: Why aren't you using a plain array of 52 cards? Also, why don't you just create a copy of the sorted array and *then* shuffle the copy?

Comment: " Could anyone point out anything wrong with my functions that would explain the output?" --> Posted code has no output.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: That `rowToSwap < 0 || rowToSwap > 3 && colToSwap < 0 || colToSwap > 12` looks wrong. I think you meant `rowToSwap < 0 || rowToSwap > 3 || colToSwap < 0 || colToSwap > 12`.

Comment: Note: `rowToSwap < 0 || rowToSwap > 3 && colToSwap < 0 || colToSwap > 12` same as `rowToSwap < 0 || (rowToSwap > 3 && colToSwap) < 0 || colToSwap > 12`, yet not _the_ issue.

Comment: `shuffleDeck()` is modifying the original deck in place as well as creating a new deck. You should probably copy the original cards to the shuffled deck first, and then shuffle the new deck in place.

Comment: `shuffleDeck()` is using the wrong algorithm.  See [Fisher Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica with all due respect there is clearly program output... thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @chessfordays Yes post has output, but   _code_ does not have output commands like `printf()`, etc thus the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022386/c-program-why-is-my-card-shuffling-function-not-working-correctly?noredirect=1#comment123781068_70022386) was "Posted code has no output" and not "Post has no output" .  By not showing the code used to see the generated output, for all we know, that code is amiss.  Hence the benefit of a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@chux** suggested using a Fisher-Yates shuffle.  The "inside out" variant of Fisher-Yates allows the new deck shuffled as it is being copied from the old deck. Fisher-Yates works on a 1-D array, but a little bit of math can be used to modify it for use on a 2-D array:

```
char *(*shuffleDeck(char *(*deck)[13]))[13]
{
    char *(*shuffledDeck)[13] = malloc(4 * sizeof(*shuffledDeck));

    /* Use "inside out" Fisher-Yates shuffle, modified for 2-D array. */
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
            int b = randInt(i * 13 + j + 1);
            int a = b / 13;
            b -= 13 * a;
            /*
             * Note: a*13+b <= i*13+j,
             * so &shuffledDeck[a][b] <= &shuffledDeck[i][j]
             */
            if (a != i || b != j) {
                shuffledDeck[i][j] = shuffledDeck[a][b];
            }
            shuffledDeck[a][b] = deck[i][j];
        }
    }
    return shuffledDeck;
}
```

The `b = randInt(i * 13 + j + 1)` function call used above returns a random integer less than its parameter value. The argument `i * 13 + j + 1` is one more than the number of cards shuffled so far. The `a = b / 13;` `b -= a * 13;` statements convert that random number to row `a`, column `b`. Crucially,  `a * 13 + b <= i * 13 + j`, so the random position (a,b) is less than or equal to the position (i,j).

If the random position (a,b) is less than the current position (i,j), a card in the shuffled deck is copied from position (a,b) to position (i,j). Then the random position (a,b) in the shuffled deck has either never been set (if the random position is the same as the current position) or contains a stale copy. In either case, the card from the current position (i,j) from the unshuffled deck is copied to the random position (a,b) in the shuffled deck.

At the end, all cards from the unshuffled deck have been copied to random but unique positions in the shuffled deck.

Here is an implementation of the `randInt` function used above:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Return random integer from 0 to n-1 (for n in range 1 to RAND_MAX+1u) */
int randInt(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int x = (RAND_MAX + 1u) / n;
    unsigned int limit = x * n;
    int s;
    do {
        s = rand();
    } while (s >= limit);
    return s / x;
}
```

Note that a simple `rand() % n` usually results in a slightly biased result. The `randInt(n)` function above uses `rand()` but produces an unbiased result.

The random number generator needs to be seeded by the `srand` function. That should be done only once in the program, e.g. from the `main` function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    /* other stuff */
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the detailed response

Comment: Is there a reason why the fisher yates method is superior to the algorithm I have?

Comment: A better than usual `randInt(unsigned n)`, nice.

Comment: @chessfordays I think your method (when corrected) goes through each position in the deck and swaps the card at that position with the card at a random position in the deck. The Wikipedia page on Fisher-Yate's shuffle calls that the [Naïve method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Na%C3%AFve_method) and describes it as "biased and fundamentally broken", citing [The Danger of Naïveté](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/).

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you can remove the while loop and just call rand % value for row and column once. Second, you should replace those integers with constants. Why put `3+1-0` instead of `NUM_ROWS`? Third, you should only call srand once, otherwise you reset the seed for your random number generator.

Lastly, the logical error in your code. I think you're missing the function definition for you last tag, but it looks like the issue is that within swap, you swap the cards, and withing your shuffle_deck function you also set shuffled_deck equal to the shuffled value. Either swap the cards in deck in place (i.e. in swap), or make a copy and shuffle your copy.